# AngularJS factory function to find sum of item in an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, parse-platform

so hopefully this will be the last step to a finally putting together my delivery app. Ok so with tons of help from members here I have a situation where an array of product items have an array of flavors attached. in the flavors array within the item array there is a price field. I have a total function in my OrderFunctions factory that returns the sum of all the active items. What i need to accomplish is to have this function take into account the selected flavor options price field. an update the returned total.. here is what i have.. thanks for looking

first my factory

```
app.factory('OrderFunctions', function() {
    var OrderFactory = {};

    OrderFactory.total = function(item){

        var total = 0;

        angular.forEach(item, function(item){
            if (item.active){
            total+= item.qty * item.price;
            }
        });

    return total;
    };
    return OrderFactory;

});
```

here is my controller these function will all be put in the factory but for now

```
app.controller('OptionsController', function($scope, OrderFunctions) {

$scope.remove = OrderFunctions.toggleActive;
$scope.add = OrderFunctions.add;
$scope.minus = OrderFunctions.minus;

$scope.addOption = function(item, opt) {
    var index = item.flavors.indexOf(opt);
    if(index > -1) {
        item.flavors.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else
        item.flavors.push(opt);
}

$scope.checkOption = function(item, opt) {
    return item.flavors.indexOf(option) > -1
}   

});
```

html markup for options page

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
     <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
          <md-card-content class="content">
              <h2 class="md-title">{{ item.name }}</h2>
              <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
              <md-list>
                  <p class="md-subhead">Choose Your Flavor</p>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item ng-repeat="option in options.results" 
                                layout="row">
                      <p> {{ option.name }} </p>
                      <span flex></span>
                      <p> {{ option.price | currency}} </p>
                      <md-checkbox aria-label="option"
                                   class="md-accent" 
                                   ng-checked="checkOption(item, option)"
                                   ng-click="addOption(item, option)">
                      </md-checkbox>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
           </md-card-content>
           <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                          layout-align="end center">
                          <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                     aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                     ng-click="remove(item)"                               
                                     ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                          </md-button>
            </md-action-bar>
  </md-card>
```

html markup for order page

```
<md-card>
<md-card-content>
    <md-list>
        <span class="md-subhead">Review Order</span>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true" 
                  layout="row">
                  <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
                  <span flex></span>
                  <span>{{ item.price | currency}}</span>
                  <div ng-repeat="flavor in item.flavors">[{{flavor.name}} : {{flavor.price | currency}}] </div>         
    </md-list-item>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item layout="row">
                      <span>Order Total :</span>
                      <span flex></span>
                      <span>{{ total(items.results) | currency}}</span>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>   
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

all this data is stored in Parse database with these name,price,desc,img,qty,active,flavors[] fields

and the options have name,price,active fields

thanks for looking and thanks to this great community whom without i never would have gotten this far...

**EDIT**

i just realized the checked box does not stay active across views, so if you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

**solved**

i went with a different approach by using what i had already

html checkbox added ng-click add() function to make the option active

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="option.active"
             class="md-accent" 
             ng-click="add(option)">
</md-checkbox>
```

than filtered those results using true

```
<span ng-repeat="option in options.results | filter:true">{{option.name}} : {{option.price | currency}}</span>
```

works great still having trouble keeping the active state of the checkbox itself but by doing this approach i feel is better because if i add different array with different options i will not have to recode anything just provide a different parameter to my add() function

here is my add() function but its pretty generic

```
OrderFactory.add = function(item){
    item.active = !item.active;
};
```

also updatted my total function in my factory to

```
OrderFactory.total = function(item, option){

    var total = 0;
    var itemTotal = 0;
    var optionTotal = 0;

    angular.forEach(item, function(item){
        if (item.active){
            itemTotal+= item.qty * item.price;
        }
    });
    angular.forEach(option, function(option){
        if (option.active){
            optionTotal+= option.price;
        }
    });
    total = itemTotal + optionTotal;
    return total;
};
```